# How to load a type from the type's name and the assembly's name

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to get an instance of a type whose name and assembly name I will have at runtime. I know in advance the type will have a parameterless constructor. What's the easiest way to do this?

It's waaaaaaay harder than I was hoping it would be.

Edit: I'm not if this is relevant, but the assembly will be referenced. I don't need to load it from disk or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Type.GetType(string.Concat(typeName, ", ", assemblyName))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx

Comment: This is the method I got working some I'm marking this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx):

> **Activator.CreateInstance Method (String, String)**
>
> Creates an instance of the type whose name is specified, using the named assembly and default constructor.
>
> ```
> public static ObjectHandle CreateInstance(
>   string assemblyName,
>   string typeName
> )
> ```

*Example:*

```
var assemblyName =
    "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";

var typeName = "System.Net.WebClient";

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName).Unwrap();
```

Comment: @David: What was the problem? I've added a working example; does that help?

Comment: It's possible that it didn't work because I wasn't specifying Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken for the assembly. But not examples seem to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If referencing System.Web.dll is not an issue for you, there is the little-known [BuildManager.GetType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z5yws8.aspx) which is quite efficient. It does not even requires the assembly name because it scans for types in assemblies in the current AppDomain execution path.

So the code would be:

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(BuildManager.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass", true));
```

Comment: Little-known indeed. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Very useful and handy. Would be even more useful if core >_<

Answer (score 2):

The following should suffice:

```
var assmebly = Assembly.Load("FullyQualifiedAssemblyName");
var type = assmebly.GetType("FullTypeName");
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Type referencedType = typeof(AReferencedType);
AReferencedType instance = Activator.CreateInstance<AReferencedType>();

or 

Type type = Type.GetType("Type's full name");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: In the second snippet, does GetType not also require the name of the assembly? I thought it did.

Comment: @David, not if you use the fully qualified type name http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx

Comment: Well, that kind of needs the name of the assembly. Anyway, it's all good.

Comment: @David, yes, it's .net's way to uniquely identify a type with a string. Please note that the second method is not safe is case of refactoring (no error at build time if you change the type's name).

Comment: You're absolutely right about the lack of safety but I don't see a way around that. A reference to the type invoked has to be stored in a database somehow...

Comment: @David I though you had a reference to the assembly in your client. In such a case, you can retrieve the type without using its name.

Answer (score 2):

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
```

[Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

[Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

Comment: I only have the names of the assembly and class at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that works using the fancy `dynamic` keyword. You'll need to reference the other class for the test to pass, or use a build event to copy over the built DLL.

```
namespace TestLibrary
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void FileCheck()
        {
            dynamic otherClass = 
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("OtherLibrary.dll",                
                    "Prefix.OtherLibrary.SomeClass");
            otherClass.SayHello();   // look, ma! no casting or interfaces!
        }
    }
}

namespace Prefix.OtherLibrary
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world.");
        }
    }
}
```

Unlike `Activator`, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` takes a *filename* as the first argument rather than a type specifier. This is sometimes useful, especially when you don't care about the strong name of the assembly.

Comment: Interesting approach. Do I know you?